# Incorrect output with counting and tallying bits in C

Tags: c, arrays, loops, bit

This is only my 2nd programming class. There are 30 rooms.  We have to see what is in each room and tally it. I already used the `for` loop to go through the 30 rooms and I know I have tried to use a bit counter to see what is in each room.  I am not getting the correct sample output after I redirect the sample output.  When I `printf("%d", itemCnt[loc]);`, my output is 774778414trolls

When I `printf("%d", itemCnt[0]);`, my output is 0trolls. I'm just trying to get one output right so I can figure out how to get the rest of the 8 outputs. From the sample output, the first number is supposed to be 6, followed by 6, 1, 4, 4 ... and so on. Below are sample inputs/outputs and what I have so far in code.

Sample input:

```
1   20  @@
2   21  @A
3   22  @#
4   23  @1
5   22  @@
6   22  @@
7   22  @@
8   22  @@
9   23  @Z  Here be trolls � not!
10  23  @+
12  23  @@
13  24  @@
11  22  @@
14  22  @2
15  21  @1
16  20  @@
17  19  @@
18  20  @@
19  19  @@
20  18  @@
21  17  @*
22  16  @*
23  15  @%
0   14  @7
0   gold_bar
1   silver_bar
2   diamond
3   copper_ring
4   jumpy_troll
5   air
6   angry_troll
7   plutonium_troll
```

Sample Output:

```
6   gold_bar
6   silver_bar
1   diamond
4   copper_ring
4   jumpy_troll
8   air
15  angry_troll
0   plutonium_troll
```

code

```
int main()
{
    // contains x and y coordinate
    int first, second;
    char third[100];
    char fourth[100];
    char Map[30][30];

    // map initialization
    for(int x=0; x<30; x++){
        for(int y=0; y<30; y++){
            Map[x][y] = '.';
        }
    }

    while(scanf("%d %d %s",&first, &second, third) != -1) {
        // Condition 1: a zero coordinate
        if (first==0 || second==0) exit(0);
        // Condition 2: coordinate out of range
        if (first<0 || first>30 || second<0 || second>30){
            printf("Error: out of range 0-30!\n");
            exit(1);
        }


        Map[second-1][first-1] = third[1];
        fgets(fourth, 100, stdin);

        // bit counter
        int itemCnt[8] = {0};         // array to hold count of items, index is item type
        unsigned char test;           // holds contents of room.
        int loc;
        for(loc = 0; loc < 8; loc++)  // loop over every bit and see if it is set
        {
            unsigned char bitPos = 1 << loc;  // generate a bit-mask
            if((test & bitPos) == bitPos)
                ++itemCnt[loc];
        }
        // print the map
        for(int h=0; h<30; h++){
            for(int v=0; v<30; v++){
                printf("%c", Map[h][v]);
            }
            printf("\n");
            }
        // print values
        printf("%d", itemCnt[0]);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please do some research on your own. stack overflow is no tutorial site. You got answers already for the similar question some hours ago. If you have problems with the answers, comment.

Comment: 0) `0   14  @7` => `if (first==0 || second==0) exit(0);` => exit program. 1) `if((test & bitPos) == bitPos)` : `test` isn't initialize and never set.

Comment: You need to describe your problem in more detail than "not getting the correct sample output". What exactly are you getting? And what have you done to debug the problem on your own and what exactly don't you know how to do? "It doesn't work, fix it for me" type questions tend not to be received well.

Comment: when i printf("%d", itemCnt[loc]); my output is 774778414trolls
when i printf("%d", itemCnt[0]); my output is 0trolls
i'm just trying to get one output right so i can figure out how to get all 8 outputs. 
sample output is supposed to be : 6   gold_bar
6   silver_bar
1   diamond
4   copper_ring
4   jumpy_troll
8   air
15  angry_troll
0   plutonium_troll

Comment: Please do not put important question information into the comments. It can be easily missed and also does not allow for proper formatting. Update your question description with all the relevant information that a reader would need to know.

Comment: Have you got this working, yet?

Answer (score 0):

`test` is not initialized.  It looks like you intended to assign 'third[1]' to `test`.

Also, 774778414 = 0x2E2E2E2E in hex, and 0x2E is the numeric value of ASCII '.', your initial value for map locations.  (Tip:  when you see wild decimals like that, try Google.  I entered, "774778414 in hex" without the quotes.)

I would also suggest breaking down the code into two functions:  the first reads from stdin to populate Map (like you do), and the second reads from stdin to populate 8 C strings to describe your objects.  It's important to note, the first loop should not go until end of input, because your posted input continues with descriptions, not strictly 3 fields like the beginning.